# I need help turning all black pixels to red in Python

Tags: python

For my CompSci homework I am supposed to create a function that changes all black pixels in a picture to red. I think I may have over complicated things. We are only allowed to use the cImage / image module.

```
from image import *

def setRed(oldPixel):
    newRed = 255 
    newGreen = 0
    newBlue = 0
    newPixel = Pixel(newRed, newGreen, newBlue)
    return newPixel
def blacktored(imageFile):
    myImage = FileImage(imageFile)
    _width = myImage.getWidth()
    _height = myImage.getHeight()
    myWindow = ImageWin(_height, _width, "window")

    for x in range(_width):
        for i in range(_height):
            oldPixel = myImage.getPixel(x, i)
            intensitySum = oldPixel.getRed() + oldPixel.getGreen() + oldPixel.getBlue()
            if intensitySum == 0:

                newPixel = setRed(oldPixel)
                myImage.setPixel(_width, _height, newPixel)
    myImage.draw(myWindow)

blacktored("mickey.png")
```

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keega\hoemworktonight.py", line 25, in <module>
    blacktored("mickey.png")
  File "C:\Users\keega\hoemworktonight.py", line 22, in blacktored
    myImage.setPixel(_width, _height, newPixel)
  File "C:\Users\keega\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\image.py", line 436, in setPILPixel
    raise ValueError("Pixel index out of range")
ValueError: Pixel index out of range
```

Can somebody help me understand why I'm getting this error, and how to fix it? I'm pretty sure all my code is good provided I can get past that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myImage.setPixel(_width, _height, newPixel)
```

This will always be out of range because the width is one greater than the maximum x-coordinate (same for the height).  I think you meant to use `x` and `i` instead of `_width` and `height`.

Comment: yep! I realized it when cross referencing my setPixel function to a similar homework assignment I had yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In line 22, i had written:

```
                myImage.setPixel(_width, _height, newPixel)
```

When I should have written

```
                myImage.setPixel(x, i, newPixel)
```